# HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm  using `AVD` to run my app. I can see it display the `android` black screen, but it display this in my `Android Studio`.

```
emulator: device fd:620
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 40 81 335 557
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install haxm installer from SDK manager

for that go to TOOLS > android >sdk manager >standalone SDK manager
then install packages